# "to become the wall off which"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, sentence, phrase-meaning

What does the highlighted part of the sentence mean? It doesn't parse for me:

> This "primal You" *becomes the wall off which* the ball can
>   bounce, the subject to which paired qualities can stick, the framework on which the full-fledged Other will be built.

Comment: Sorry, we don’t do literary criticism here. But the short story is that read like PoMo ... which infamously has multiple interpretations.

Comment: I am not looking for criticism or something like that. I am translating a book from English. I just can not understand the meaning of"to become the wall off which the ball can bounce". is it an Idiom if yes what it means?

Comment: Sorry, “literary criticism” means “interpretation of a text”, not “a critique of a text”. But if you’re just wondering about the “wall” part: no, it’s not an idiom, it’s just a metaphor: picture a wall. Now picture throwing a rubber ball against the wall. It bounces off. Every time you throw the ball, it bounces off the wall. It must. So in that thing you’re asking about, “the primal You” is the wall, and something else is the ball, and the ball bounces off the wall. I know that’s not totally helpful, but anything more becomes interpretation... of a messy text.

Comment: I am not familiar with such idiom. The meaning must be derived by context, which you have not supplied. As it is, it mean simply that this "primal You" becomes a wall. What kind of wall? A wall off which the ball can bounce. What ball? Your snippet does not say.

Comment: thank you guys; this is the full paragraph:Instinct, then, solves the problem of foundation. If we maintain that
there is an instinctual presence of the Other as "primal You," then pairing
can take place. This "primal You" becomes the wall off which the ball can
bounce, the subject to which paired qualities can stick, the framework on
which the full-fledged Other will be built. Consequently, the infant comes
with a built-in awareness of the Other at a very basic level, and this makes
possible the success of the pairing relation and the infant's inevitable
achievement of Egohood.

Comment: in this paragraph:Instinct, then, solves the problem of foundation. If we maintain that
there is an instinctual presence of the Other as "primal You," then pairing
can take place. This "primal You" becomes the wall off which the ball can
bounce, the subject to which paired qualities can stick, the framework on
which the full-fledged Other will be built. Consequently, the infant comes
with a built-in awareness of the Other at a very basic level, and this makes
possible the success of the pairing relation and the infant's inevitable
achievement of Egohood.

Comment: @HamidMalekzadeh Delete your comments and add this to your question.

Comment: As others have said, it’s not an idiom. It just means what the words literally mean. The entire thing is metaphorical, but not in a way that is particularly English. The same metaphor would presumably work in your own language (Farsi?) in one form or another.

Comment: I am reminded of a German professor I had in college who said that he never understood Kant until he read him in English. Similarly, what this paragraph is actually intended to mean isn't at all clear to us native English speakers, either.

Comment: Of course, you could always translate it literally, but it would be better if you can figure out what the author actually wanted this metaphor to mean and paraphrase it. Good luck!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet yes it is Farsi, Thank you I will try to find the proper form in Farsi.

Comment: @PeterShor it is somehow about phenomenology; and Husserl. I think, regardinh what every one said about the sentence,it means it prepares the essencial side by which the pairing can be strted; just like what a waal dose n bouncing the bal or something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This "primal You" becomes the wall off which the ball can bounce...

This is slightly more formal grammar. Nowadays people will be more likely to say

> This thing becomes the wall that the ball can bounce off.

These are both transformations from sentences with prepositional phrases and asking a question about the object of the preposition:

> The ball can bounce *off of the wall*

which transforms into:

> What thing can the ball bounce off?

or

> Off which thing can the ball bounce?

(in order to avoid the preposition at the end of the sentence that some stylists disdain)